# How to configure jboss to run as a service in rhel 7

Tags: jboss7.x, rhel7, jboss-eap-7

How to run jboss as a service if installed using  zip package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the coresponding JBoss EAP 7 documentation [Installation Guide - Configuring JBoss EAP to run as a Service](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/installation_guide/configuring_jboss_eap_to_run_as_a_service) for detailed information.